# Story about a European captain marrying a tribal woman, part of the plot similar to *The Count of Monte Cristo*?

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to find the name of a story. The plot is set in the age when Europeans were sailing to the Americas and contacting the local tribes. My memory is vague but here are some of the points I can remember and hopefully in the order they happened:

- ***This is probably not how the story begins but is the earliest event I can remember.*** The captain of a ship docked somewhere in Americas need food for the crew and tries to get corn from the local tribals which they grow plentyful. The tribals demand guns/artillery in exchange for corn. The deal happens and also leads more transaction. Slowly the relationship between the visitors and the tribals starts to get better.
- The captain falls in love with one of the local women (most likely the chief's daughter?). There is a huge uproar among the tribals due to this, of course! But, somehow they get married and they return to Europe (my best guess is Portugal). They have a good life there.
- ***Can't remember what happens from there, maybe he went on the next voyage?*** But, for some reason the captain is now imprisoned in a remote island similar to what happens in *The Count of Monte Cristo*. ***This could be following a shipwreck.***
- In prison, the captain interacts with a man (but doesn't see him, though) who promises him that he could escape if he manages to somehow remove a particular brick. Over a period of time he manages to shake and remove the brick from the wall, squeezes past the wall and gets to the other side. But to his dismay, realises that he only managed to get to the adjacent cell.
- The next door neighbour who happens to be an old man is the one who promised the escape. The captain is mad that he wasted all this time only to get to the next cell. The captain gets back to his cell and puts the brick back.
- One day the old man dies and the guards put his body into a sack and plan to throw him into the sea. The captain grabs this opportunity and 'switches' position when the guards go out of the prison cell. Finally he is free. He later on reunites with his wife. ***Of course, I am sure there will be more to the story before reuniting with his wife.***

A few points to note:

- I watched this as an animation almost 2 decades ago but I am guessing it might be a famous novel or something.
- Thinking back about the quality of the animation it may be from the 80s or even 70s.
- This is not *The Count of Monte Cristo* as the protagonist is married to a South American woman and it is definitely not *Pocahontas*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, you saw this story in the format of an animated *film* and you're not certain if this is the plot of a novel or not?

Comment: Yes, I saw this as an animated film but I don't know the name of the film. Since many animated films are based on novels, just wondering if this animation  is also based on some kind of noval. Basically trying to find anything related to this. Thanks

Comment: Maybe The Road to El Dorado? Another Disney animation that was produced about two decades ago.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I read the plot of Road to El Dorado and that story is different from what I am looking for.